# Solution for subquery in MySQL WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, where-in

I am trying to solve WHERE subquery or to find different solution.
What I am trying to achieve is based on this query:

```
SELECT c.orig_point_id, 
   (SELECT attempts 
    FROM 
       (SELECT 
            orig_carrier_id, 
            orig_point_id, 
            term_point_id, 
            term_route, 
            currency_sell, 
            is_special, 
            COUNT(*) AS attempts 
        FROM cdr 
        WHERE 1=1 
            AND start_time >= '2016-10-01 0:00:00' 
            AND start_time <= '2016-10-31 23:59:59' 
        GROUP BY orig_carrier_id, currency_sell) AS c0 
    WHERE c0.orig_carrier_id=3 
        AND c0.currency_sell="USD" 
    LIMIT 1) AS attempts,
   (SELECT SPLIT(clear_number) as array 
   FROM 
       (SELECT 
           COUNT(*) as total, 
           clear_number, 
           orig_carrier_id,
           currency_sell 
       FROM `cdr` 
       WHERE `start_time`>='2016-10-01 00:00:00' 
           AND start_time <= '2016-10-31 23:59:59' 
       GROUP BY `clear_number` 
       ORDER BY total DESC) AS c0 
   WHERE c0.orig_carrier_id=3 
       AND c0.currency_sell="USD" 
   LIMIT 1) AS splitted_number
FROM cdr AS c 
GROUP BY c.orig_carrier_id, c.currency_sell;
```

SPLIT is a function. Query in that section finds a number(most frequent) and function splits it in ex. 12345,1234,123,12,1. Problem comes when i try to use that as IN subquery. When used directly mysql says functionality not supported. Looks like query is too complex.
When i alias subquery as a workaround it returns NULL, so workaround doesn't work and i believe its returning NULL because of the same reason that its not feasible.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(" - ",country,region) AS route_name 
FROM numbering_plan_external 
WHERE 
    prefix IN(
        SELECT array 
        FROM 
            (SELECT SPLIT(clear_number) as array 
            FROM 
                (SELECT 
                    COUNT(*) as total, 
                    clear_number, 
                    orig_carrier_id,
                    currency_sell 
                FROM `cdr` 
                WHERE `start_time`>='2016-10-01 00:00:00' 
                    AND start_time <= '2016-10-31 23:59:59' 
                GROUP BY `clear_number` 
                ORDER BY total DESC) AS c0 
            WHERE c0.orig_carrier_id=3 
                AND c0.currency_sell="USD" 
            LIMIT 1) AS splitted_number) 
        ORDER BY prefix DESC LIMIT 1) AS top_route
```

Am I doing anything wrong here, or is there different approach to achieve this. I can leave just split number and later through PHP find the route. It will require lots of queries depending on the results and I am trying to avoid it if possible.

Thanks in advance guys.

Some sample data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `numbering_plan_external` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`region` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`prefix` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`is_mobile` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`last_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`min_sale_price_currency` char(3) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`min_sale_price_amount` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14004 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `numbering_plan_external` 
(`id`, `country`, `region`,`prefix`, `is_mobile`, `last_updated`, `min_sale_price_currency`, `min_sale_price_amount`) 
VALUES
(13047, 'Tunisia', '', '216', 0, '2016-02-17 12:30:44', NULL, NULL),
(13048, 'Tunisia', 'Mobile (ORANGE)', '2165', 1, '2016-02-17 12:30:44', NULL, NULL),
(13049, 'Tunisia', 'Mobile (ORASCOM)', '2162', 1, '2016-02-17 12:30:44', NULL, NULL),
(13050, 'Tunisia', 'Mobile (TUNTEL)', '21640', 1, '2016-02-17 12:30:44', NULL, NULL),
(13051, 'Tunisia', 'Mobile (TUNTEL)', '21641', 1, '2016-02-17 12:30:44', NULL, NULL),
(13052, 'Tunisia', 'Mobile (TUNTEL)', '2169', 1, '2016-02-17 12:30:44', NULL, NULL);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cdr` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`orig_carrier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`orig_point_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`term_carrier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`term_point_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`clear_number` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`is_special` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`start_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`currency_sell` char(3) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16385 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `cdr` 
(`id`, `orig_carrier_id`, `orig_point_id`, `term_carrier_id`, `term_point_id`, `clear_number`, `is_special`, `start_time`, `currency_sell`) VALUES
(1, 3, 5, 0, 0, '21658502507', 0, '2016-10-17 00:02:04', 'USD'),
(2, 3, 5, 0, 0, '21658502507', 0, '2016-10-17 00:02:04', 'USD'),
(3, 3, 5, 0, 0, '21658502507', 0, '2016-10-17 00:03:56', 'USD'),
(4, 3, 5, 0, 0, '21658502507', 0, '2016-10-17 00:09:28', 'USD'),
(5, 3, 5, 0, 0, '21658502507', 0, '2016-10-17 00:16:35', 'USD');
```

Comment: if you provide sample data (as inserts or text we can reuse) and then also the expected result we could then propose a better solution. (a sample does not have to be large!)

Comment: Added some sample data.

Comment: What is the relevance of table `numbering_plan_external`? All I see in the query is `cdr`. It would be beneficial for you to also explain what you expect as the result of the query from that data. e.g. right now (from that data) I see no reason for a split function.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Relevance of `numbering plan external `table can be found in second subquery. It begin with ` SELECT CONCAT_WS(" - ",country,region) AS route_name ... ` After the most hitting number is found, eg. 21658502507, SPLIT will produce a list of same number with last digit cutoff 21658502507, 2165850250, 216585025 .. 2. It is used to find longest prefix match from external plan which is in our case: ` 'Tunisia', 'Mobile (ORANGE)', '2165' ` Sorry for not explaining it at the first place.

Comment: @Used_By_Already In my post where I said that i made alias of that entire subquery what i meant is that I replaced entire block that begins with ` (SELECT SPLIT(clear_number) ... AS splitted_number ` with section that comes next beginning with ` SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(" - ",country,region) AS route_name ... `

Comment: I have added a new query that includes both tables.

Comment: Have you abandoned this question? I have added a full solution, at least some recognition of this would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` considers values as a whole. Whatever your `SPLIT()` is doing, even though it returns a "csv", that entire list is considered one SINGLE value, e.g. it'll be parsed/executed as the equivalent

```
WHERE foo IN ('12345,1234,...')
WHERE foo='12345,1234,...'
```

instead of these

```
WHERE foo IN ('12345', '1234', '123', ...)
WHERE foo='12345' OR foo='1234' OR ...
```

You could try using MySQL's [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead, which basically does what you want.

Comment: thanks. actually a query with list as <code>SELECT CONCAT_WS(" - ",country,region) AS route_name FROM numbering_plan_external WHERE prefix IN
(21658502507,2165850250,216585025,21658502,2165850,216585,21658,2165,216,21,2) ORDER BY prefix DESC LIMIT 1<code> gives results just fine

Comment: You were very much right about considering the value as a whole. `find_in_set ` helped in this case. Now my entire subquery works fine.

Comment: note that find_in_set is very inefficient. it's basically a substring search/match, and can't use indexes. If it becomes an issue, you'll have to redesign to a properly normalized design, rather than using "csv" data.

Comment: Yes, i have already noticed that, you are right. And also its kind of slow. I will try to make a ready-made value to be used in ` IN `.

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample data with this query:

```
SELECT
      cdr.orig_point_id
    , count(cdr.*) attempts 
    , group_concat(distinct npe.region) regions
FROM cdr
INNER JOIN numbering_plan_external npe
        ON cdr.clear_number like concat(npe.prefix,'%') COLLATE latin1_general_ci
        AND npe.region <> ''
WHERE cdr.orig_carrier_id=3 
  AND cdr.currency_sell='USD' 
  AND cdr.start_time >= '2016-10-01' 
  AND cdr.start_time <  '2016-11-01' 
GROUP BY
      cdr.orig_point_id
;
```

Result:

```
| orig_point_id | attempts |   regions      |
|---------------|----------|----------------|
|             5 |        5 | Mobile (ORANGE)|
```

The join between those tables involves comparing the prefix to the starting characters of the clear_number. However you have a collation conflict so you need to specify the collation being used. Using LIKE is not the most efficient style of join condition and it could lead to performance issues as it doesn't make use of indexes. However it does demonstrate that a logical join does exist and that you do not need that split function (which is not good for a join either by the way).

---

I have left the remainder of my earlier question available for reference:

**Query**:

```
SELECT
      orig_point_id
    , count(*) attempts 
FROM cdr
WHERE orig_carrier_id=3 
  AND currency_sell='USD' 
  AND start_time >= '2016-10-01' 
  AND start_time <  '2016-11-01' 
GROUP BY
      orig_point_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40aa8/3/0)**:

```
| orig_point_id | attempts |
|---------------|----------|
|             5 |        5 |
```

**extracted for Original Query**:

```
SELECT c.orig_point_id, 
   (SELECT attempts 
    FROM 
       (SELECT 
            orig_carrier_id, 
            orig_point_id, 
            term_point_id, 
            /* term_route, */
            currency_sell, 
            is_special, 
            COUNT(*) AS attempts 
        FROM cdr 
        WHERE 1=1 
            AND start_time >= '2016-10-01 0:00:00' 
            AND start_time <= '2016-10-31 23:59:59' 
        GROUP BY orig_carrier_id, currency_sell) AS c0 
    WHERE c0.orig_carrier_id=3 
        AND c0.currency_sell="USD" 
    LIMIT 1) AS attempts
FROM cdr AS c 
GROUP BY c.orig_carrier_id, c.currency_sell
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40aa8/3/1)**:

```
| orig_point_id | attempts |
|---------------|----------|
|             5 |        5 |
```

Hopefully you can see that you do not need as much complexity in your query as you do now. I suspect that if we know more about the "expected result" we might be able to do it without the split function.